# How can a race that relies on echo location to "see" protect against sonic weapons?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, technology

I am interested in adding a race that relies on echolocation to sense the world around them in my scfi/fantasy setting.  What I'm wondering is, **how can a race protect against highly advanced sonic weaponry that is designed to target their hearing?**

I would like to know if there is a way for them fight on even if such weapons are deployed.

Assume human level intelligence and are technologically advanced in sonic technology.

Comment: You didn't even try Googling keywords from your own question b4 asking did you? [protection against sonic](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&biw=1280&bih=616&tbm=shop&sxsrf=ACYBGNShjo6BKNVS-LChpx-4-0Wu16903Q%3A1572167564014&ei=jF-1XY1A3oCFsg_085VY&q=protection+against+sonic+&oq=protection+against+sonic+&gs_l=psy-ab-sh.12...29774.29774.0.30823.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab-sh..0.0.0....0.oJGZ4ni7uok), "active ear protectors" will get you better hits, but still.. no research at all b4 asking [-]

Comment: Presumably they'd be fighting their own kind, and given the way sound propagates, would mean a lot of friendly fire if deployed at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Military grade active noise cancelling headphones.

Even if it only reduces sound to a tolerable level, that's less incapacitated soldiers. Furthermore, if they can update software to ignore the weapon frequencies, then the weapons could become ineffective.

If their tech is advanced enough, it can be tweaked to allow for their own sonar pulses, and even other sounds, but only those below a certain volume threshold and within a good range of frequencies.

Comment: How?  can you send some sources to me?

Comment: @Seraphim : Just Google ***"active ear protectors"*** & you'll get a bunch of hits, they're commercially available, I've had a pair of ear plugs that do it I bought over 20 years ago, the newer full headphone ones available now should do a much better job, it's old & widely known to exist (to anyone who's ever done ***any*** firearms training or sports shooting) common & easy to find equipment.

Comment: Won't that also blind them if they need echolocation to see?

Comment: @Halfthawed: Not necessarily. You could have them designed to generate a 180 degree phase inverted signal to the incoming noise, to neutralise it, then transmit that signal at a fixed amplitude to the receiver's ear. On the negative side all noises will be equally loud, so you miss out on distances and gradients.

Comment: @nzaman : _"On the negative side all noises will be equally loud, **so you miss out on distances** and gradients"_ eh!? echolocation remember, it doesn't work on volume.

Comment: @Pelinore: The most likely way to judge distance with sonar is the delay and loudness of the return signal. That tells you both how far away the object is and how hard it probably is. Now, if your return signal is delayed due to the processing in your headphones and the resultant is at a normalised volume (loudness) your distance judgement is compromised

Comment: @nzaman : volume (how '_loud_') has nothing to do with determining distance with echolocation (as you have said it does in the comment I was responding to) : 'loudness' is affected by a lot of other things including the 'softness' or 'texture' (it's sound absorption properties) of the surface it's reflecting from so that's not what is used, the delay is what's used, those headphones do not 'delay' the sound.

Comment: @Pelinore: Signal strength is a factor in determining primary reflections and echoes. If the reflection from a nearby object is as loud as the reflection from a distant object and the echo from a previous wave, that is a problem

Comment: @nzaman : then it's a problem then because it's how things are [shrugs] : [Absorption (acoustics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_(acoustics)) ***"In general, soft, pliable, or porous materials (like cloths) serve as good acoustic insulators - absorbing most sound, whereas dense, hard, impenetrable materials (such as metals) reflect most."***

Comment: @nzaman : ^ but personally I'd call it an advantage, you get a fast but quiet return ping from dead ahead you'll know it's close but also soft, going to be a soft landing (or crash), it's extra information, but it (volume) isn't what you use to determine distance with echo location (which is what your comment said).

Comment: @Pelinore: Clearly I'm not expressing myself very well. Let's say Ping is the initial sonar wave and Pong is the reflected response detected. So, assuming that this line is the time axis, under normal conditions you get: PING...PONG (nearby solid object)pong(nearby soft object)...PING...$_{pong}$(echo)PONGpong... With volume normalization, you get: PING...pong (nearby solid object)pong(nearby soft object)...PING...pong(echo)pongpong... Are we seeing the problem here?

Comment: @nzaman : Bear in mind also that active ear defenders don't make all sounds the same volume, they only damp noises above the damaging threshold [not read your last comment yet, that's just an addition to my previous].

Comment: @nzaman : OK [read it] I still don't see a problem if you're seeking to avoid both objects, if your trying to decide which one to run into at full speed I do see a problem, I suspect I'm not getting what you're saying though? :) but see my previous comment, if only damagingly loud noises get muted by ear defenders that problem shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Pelinore: This entire back and forth has been based on one phrase in my comment to Halfthawed about the potential disadvantages of normalising volume, which has nothing to do with nijineko's answer. So, no, I'm not getting the point either.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less the same problem encountered by radar and jammers.

By jamming the jammer reveals a bearing to their location. If you can hear the jammer from a few different locations you can triangulate their position, then you call in the an air/artillery strike...

Answer (score 1):

keep your echolocation quiet (quite useful anyway in a war situation) and wear noise canceling headphones.
In said headgear include stereoscopic vision cameras and something that can translate vision to echolocation-returns.
This should also include some processing to remove glare so this whole setup will protect against both noise and light.

If you want to keep it lower-tech you could work with a Kinect style active system that projects infrared dots to build 3d surroundings.